# In revolution slider YouTube video playing done Doesn’t automatically go to the next slide

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

- We have used "Revolution Slider" in my site, On slider image we have added YouTube video layer and video is auto-play but video playing is completed it's doesn't automatically go to next slide.
- Site URL : http://garyskyner.com/
- We have already applied settings in slider when video play is completed it's go to next slide.

Answer (score 0):

when you have buy the plug-in give you one code you can use to ask to the assistance, it's good and sure can help you. 
If the first video when finish restart could be the second video have some problem to compatibility. If not sure you need check the setting because i have use and don't give me this problem.